# Jenkins: Back up and Restore

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying to take backup of my jenkins machine and restore it in a new machine. I copied the Jenkins home dir to the new Jenkins Home dir. All my jobs are showing up but none of the plugins are showing up under installed tab . This is what the log says :

```
SEVERE: Failed Inspecting plugin /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/._ace-editor.jpi
java.io.IOException: Failed to expand /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/._ace-editor.jpi
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:610)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:174)
        at hudson.PluginManager$1$3$1.run(PluginManager.java:394)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:999)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Error while expanding /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/._ace-editor.jpi
java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.unzipExceptClasses(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:682)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:607)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
        at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:320)
        at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:170)
        ... 13 more

Jun 22, 2017 1:38:04 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Inspecting plugin /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/ace-editor.jpi
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.addPathFile(AntClassLoader.java:502)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.addPathFiles(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:845)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createClassLoader(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:308)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:248)
        at hudson.PluginManager$1$3$1.run(PluginManager.java:394)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:999)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a know issue in [jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22095) about firewall problem